# refreshing pages gives 404 error for create-react-app websites using react-router-dom

Tags: create-react-app, react-router-dom

So I've read similar questions but answers were too complex for my understanding. I have not set up a back-end, I just use create-react-app and install react-router-dom, and while my websites can refresh on my localhost, when I upload them on internet, if I refresh any page except the home page, they give a 404 not found page error.

these are the versions of my installed programs:
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/didyoukno" component={Didyouknow}/>
                    <Route
                        render={() => (
                            <div>
                                <h1>Error 404: Not Found</h1>
                                <Link to="/">Go Home</Link>
                            </div>)}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

So turned out to deploy on a c-panel you need to add a .htaccess in the public folder with this:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Now for refreshing or history, it will refer to index.html