# Simplest way to deal with react component web addresses?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

So I've found that if I have separate "pages" built with components in a react app that those components with throw a 404 if a user tries to refresh or navigate directly to the respective address. What is the simplest fix for this?

I've already built out the majority of the app and it's a pretty basic portfolio site so I don't need a major fix and it's ok if it just redirects back to the main page that's fine.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>

            <header className="App-header">
                <nav>
                    <Link to="/" class="navlink">Main</Link>
                    <Link to="/Subpage1" class="navlink">Subpage1</Link>
                    <Link to="/Subpage2" class="navlink">Subpage2</Link>
                    <Link to="/Subpage3" class="navlink">Subpage3</Link>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <body>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                <Route path="/Subpage1" component={Subpage1} />
                <Route path="/Subpage2" component={Subpage2} />
                <Route path="/Subpage3" component={Subpage3} />
            </body>



        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add a .htaccess file with appropriate code to the public folder. Solution found on this post:

[refreshing pages gives 404 error for create-react-app websites using react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895181/refreshing-pages-gives-404-error-for-create-react-app-websites-using-react-route)